# How can I read a value from key (stringValue)?

Tags: swift

I need help....I only want to print the key value, I don't want to read all the Object

I created a QRCode using this code:

```
    @IBAction func btnCreate(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if sectionNameTxt.text == "" || sectionExtTxt.text == "" || sectionLocationTxt.text == ""  {
            
        }else{
            let dic = ["sectionName": sectionNameTxt.text!,"sectionExt": sectionExtTxt.text!,"sectionLocation": sectionLocationTxt.text!]
            print("dic:\(dic)")
            
            imgView.image = QRGenerator.generate(from: dic)

            
            
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(dic)
                
                
                if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
                    filter.setValue(jsonData, forKey: "inputMessage")
                    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
                    
                    if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                        imgView.image = UIImage(ciImage: output)
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            } catch  {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

This code is to read the QRCode:

```
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first{
            guard let readleObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else {return}
            
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

           print((readleObject.stringValue!))

            
            session.stopRunning()

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

output :

```
{"sectionName":"pharmacy","sectionExt":"1010","sectionLocation":"Main Building - Ground Floor"}
```

I want read the value of the key1(sectionName) and key2(sectionExt) and key3(sectionLocation) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSONSerialization`.

```
if let data = readleObject.stringValue.data(using: .utf8) {
     if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []), let dataDict = json as? NSDictionary {
          if let sectionName = dataDict["sectionName"] as? String  
          }

     }
}
```

You can do the rest.

Comment: `if let data` is pointless. Converting a string to utf8 will never fail  `let data = Data(readleObject.stringValue.utf8)`. Btw jsonObject options default value is already empty. You can simply omit it when calling that method. Last but not least when coding in Swift you should use native Dictionary type.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Please follow @LeoDabus recommendation.